# Deck Probabilities drawing three cards. One out of three cards drawn must be a 10.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A standard deck of playing cards is well shuffled, and three cards are selected at random without replacement. Find the Probabilities of the following event(s):

C = At least one 10 is chosen (Hint:Consider C'.)

Work:
=(4 choose 1)*(48 choose 2) / (52 choose 3)

=(4!/(4-1)! * 1!) * ( 48!/(48-2)! * 2!) / (52!/(52-3)!*3!)

=(4!/3! * 1)! * ( 48!/46! * 2!) / (52!/49!*3!)

=(4 * 1) * ( 48*47/ 2) / (52*51*50/3*2) = 0.204

Comment: Have you considered $C'$?

Comment: Yes, I considered it but still getting the answer wrong.

Comment: And... what did you do for considering $C'$?  What probability did you get for $C'$ and how did you get it?

Comment: Maybe we can show you where you went wrong in your calculation if you post your work.

Comment: The probability you found $$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{2}}{\binom{52}{3}}$$ is the probability of getting *exactly one ten*, as opposed to the probability of getting *at least one ten*.  You could, if you like, add the probability of getting exactly two tens and the probability of getting exactly three tens to get to the final correct answer.

Comment: Also, note, you simplified $\binom{48}{\color{red}{2}}$ to $\frac{48!}{(48-\color{red}{1})!\color{red}{1}!}$ instead of $\frac{48!}{(48-2)!2!}$

Comment: Okay, let me make those adjustments.

Comment: @JMoravitz after i made those adjustments is that the correct way of representing at least one 10 being drawn of the three cards?

Comment: No.  As I mentioned 22 minutes ago, that number represents the probability of getting **exactly one** ten.  Getting **exactly one** is different from getting **at least one** (exactly one or exactly two or exactly three).

Comment: Basically the way i solved only shows the probability for exactly one ten and the solution you showed me is how to get a probability for at least one ten, correct?

Comment: Correct, though as mentioned there are many different ways of calculating the probability.  As I mentioned above in the comments, you calculated $P(\text{exactly one ten})$, but you could do $P(\text{at least one ten}) = P(\text{exactly one ten})+P(\text{exactly two tens})+P(\text{exactly three tens})+\dots$  Which method you find easiest depends largely on your comfort level with the method, as well as on how many steps each would require.  Although its not so bad for this question, for a question like "probability at least 2 hearts in 13card hand" I wouldn't want to add 10 things together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may approach this in many different ways.  Here is a solution where we temporarily assume order *does* matter.

When I draw one card from a standard 52-card deck, the chance that it is *not* a 10 is:

$$\frac{48}{52}$$

since there are 48 cards in the deck that are not 10's out of 52 cards total and each were equally likely to be drawn.

*Supposing that I drew a card that isn't a 10* then there are still $47$ remaining cards which are not tens out of $51$ remaining cards in the deck.  The probability that when I draw again (having already drawn one not-ten card) that it *again* isn't a ten will be

$$\frac{47}{51}$$

By the definition of conditional probability, you have $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B|A)$.  Letting $A$ be the event that the first card drawn is not a ten, and $B$ be the event that the second card drawn is not a ten, we have $A\cap B$ is the event that neither of the first two cards is a ten.  We calculated above that $P(A)=\frac{48}{52}$ and that $P(B|A)=\frac{47}{51}$, so $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B|A)=\frac{48\cdot 47}{52\cdot 51}$.  I.e., the chance that if I draw two cards that neither of them are a ten is $\frac{48\cdot 47}{52\cdot 51}$.

See if you can generalize this to your question.

---

We may also choose to approach this where we assume that order *doesn't* matter.

The number of ways we may choose a hand of two cards which don't include tens where order doesn't matter is $\binom{48}{2}=\frac{48\cdot 47}{2}$.  The number of ways we could choose two cards where we don't care if there is a ten or not where order doesn't matter is $\binom{52}{2}=\frac{52\cdot 51}{2}$.

Since each two-card hand is equally likely, we have then the probability that choosing two cards that neither is a ten is $\frac{\binom{48}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}=\dfrac{~~\frac{48\cdot 47}{2}~~}{~~\frac{52\cdot 51}{2}~~}=\frac{48\cdot 47}{52\cdot 51}$

Not too surprisingly, we get the same answer in both scenarios.  Again, see if you can generalize this method to the case of a three card hand or a 4 card or more.

---

Complete the problem by remembering the inclusion-exclusion principle.  $P(C)=1-P(C')$